# HPE DL20 RHEL 6 kickstart installation from dvd

Tags: redhat, hp, boot, bios, uefi

I have a dvd with a RHEL 6.6 installer with its customized kickstart file for automation, and this dvd has been tested in other servers and is able to perform an installation, so it works fine.

The problem is that in my HPE DL 20 Gen9 there is no way to make it boot even if I disable UEFI. According to a workmate, he could perform an installation using the feature "Intelligent Provisioning", but there he could not use the kickstart file. The Dvd drive is listed as the first device, but it doesn't seem to seem to pick it up anyway.

I know it sounds a bit vague, but I can't provide log files to debug this either, so I was expecting that somebody that had a similar issue with HPE UEFI/BIOS could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be:

- Disable UEFI and therefore enable Legacy BIOS mode
- Disable network boot for every network card. Even if the Dvd was chosen as the first device to boot, for some reason it always tried to boot from the network.

And that's it. The system should be able to boot from Dvd now.

EDIT: After resetting the BIOS to factory settings, I've found out that the DVD drive had to be set to use AHCI in the SATA controller settings menu